# How do I import a module to a.py from another folder that imports a function from b.py

Tags: python

I've read all the other answers, but couldn't find a solution for this particular issue. I have this folder structure:

```
\project
   a.py
   \gui
       b.py
```

And the files are:

```
# a.py
import gui.b

def foo():
    pass
```

```
# b.py
from ..a import foo

if __name__ == "__main__":
    foo()
```

I don't know how to even implement this. I know I shouldn't be using relative import in b.py, but is there any other form besides messing with sys.path to be able to use pylint to autocomplete and show my function while working in b.py?

Nevertheless, when I run a.py, I get an error that foo() is not defined, but it should be as I'm running from a.py, where foo() is actually defined.

Thank you for your help

Comment: You have to put `__init__.py` in `gui` to make it a package.

Comment: But what you're trying to do is impossible anyways, because Python doesn't allow cyclic imports.